# NVIDIA Unhandled exception at 0x002a2da2 in <work.exe>0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, nvidia

I am currently trying to make two arms on a character and use NxRevoluteJoint for their movement. I have these working perfectly in another program that has been given as an example and I have used the same code in this new project however I am getting an error (the one in the title) and I am struggling how to fix it. I understand that the pointers is reference to NULL at some place but I can't see how to sort it out.

The variables are set globally:

```
NxRevoluteJoint* playerLeftJoint= 0;
NxRevoluteJoint* playerRightJoint= 0;
```

This is the code in the seperate function where the player is being built as a compound object:

```
NxVec3 globalAnchor(0,1,0);     
NxVec3 globalAxis(0,0,1);       

playerLeftJoint= CreateRevoluteJoint(0,actor2,globalAnchor,globalAxis);
playerRightJoint= CreateRevoluteJoint(0,actor2,globalAnchor,globalAxis);


//set joint limits
NxJointLimitPairDesc limit1;
limit1.low.value = -0.3f;
limit1.high.value = 0.0f;
playerLeftJoint->setLimits(limit1);


NxJointLimitPairDesc limit2;
limit2.low.value = 0.0f;
limit2.high.value = 0.3f;
playerRightJoint->setLimits(limit2);    

NxMotorDesc motorDesc1;
motorDesc1.velTarget = 0.15;
motorDesc1.maxForce = 1000;
motorDesc1.freeSpin = true;
playerLeftJoint->setMotor(motorDesc1);

NxMotorDesc motorDesc2;
motorDesc2.velTarget = -0.15;
motorDesc2.maxForce = 1000;
motorDesc2.freeSpin = true;
playerRightJoint->setMotor(motorDesc2);
```

The line where I am getting the error is at the `playerLeftJoint->setLimits(limit1);`

Comment: `NxRevoluteJoint* playerLeftJoint= 0;` You're dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: how do I go about not dereferencing it?

Comment: Make it point to an existing `NxRevoluteJoint` before using it. Similar for the right joint.

Comment: well I already have it pointing at a `NxRevoluteJoint` the `CreateRevoluteJoint` is `NxRevoluteJoint` function

Comment: That must have returned `NULL`. The error clearly says you're trying to read address 0.

Comment: @Defterniko: No, you need to study up on your basics a bit.  This statement makes no sense; *"well I already have it pointing at a NxRevoluteJoint"*.  `NxRevoluteJoint` is a type, not an instance of an object.

Comment: Consider *checking* your pointers for successful allocation prior to *using* them. You may be surprised. I can only assume that the hard assignment 6 lines prior to the pointer usage, `playerLeftJoint= CreateRevoluteJoint(0,actor2,globalAnchor,globalAxis);` failed, and is never checked before use. You may want to check the docs on that function to see when, how, and why it can fail to allocate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateRevoluteJoint` is returning a null pointer, simple as that.  The error message makes it very clear that the pointer has a value of `0`.  Of course, you didn't post that function, so that's the best information I can give you.  As such, this line;

```
playerLeftJoint->setLimits(limit1);
```

dereferences the pointer `playerLeftJoint`, which is an invalid pointer.  You need to initialize your pointers.  I can't see your entire program structure, so in this case the most simple fix would be something like;

```
if(!playerLeftJoint)
    playerLeftJoint = new NxRevoluteJoint();

// same for the other pointer, now they are valid
```

---

Additionally, as this is C++ and not C, use a smart pointer to handle memory for you, i.e.,

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<NxRevoluteJoint> playerLeftJoint;

// or, if you have a custom deallocater...
std::unique_ptr<NxRevoluteJoint, RevoluteJointDeleter> playerLeftJoint;

// ...

playerLeftJoint.reset(new NxRevoluteJoint(...));
```

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume there is a custom delete function in the API he's using to go along with the allocation function `CreateRevoluteJoint`, and if so, shouldn't the smart pointer usage include a custom Deleter template parameter to ensure the proper cleanup functionality is invoked, as it is likely not a simple heap allocation using `operator new()`?

Comment: @WhozCraig: Possibly.  However, this is a forum post, not an all encompassing solution. I don't know if that is his function or an API function.  If the OP has additional constraints not shown in the post then he should be able to use this answer and cater it to his needs. It's a good suggestion though, I'll add it.

Comment: thanks @EdS adding the smart pointer has fixed my work, it really is appreciated. Think I'm going to go off and do some reading to get a better understanding of these.

Just for future refernece if anyone comes across this the
`if(!playerLeftJoint)`
    `playerLeftJoint = new NxRevoluteJoint();`

didnt work as it is not an abstract class but i'm sure it would work for standard c++ work as this has the Nvidia API on top